# Porque o Clear retira a classe R do projeto Android?

Tags: android

Eu perdi um projeto inteiro porque eu executei um clear no projeto Android, pois ele retirou a classe R.

Porque isso acontece?
Como faço para o projeto Android gera de novo a class R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o projeto não regerou a classe R, o seu projeto tem problemas maiores.

Verifique se o seu `AndroidManifest.xml` está 100% correto, se não tem nenhum erro nas activities, nos arquivos e subpastas da pasta `res`.

A operação de Clean do Eclipse tira os arquivos temporários dos projetos que você executou a ação, e então ele reconstrói os mesmos. Então o Clean tirou a classe R, e não regerou a mesma pois o seu projeto tem problemas, como alguns que eu citei acima.

Comment: Desculpe, mas estou expondo meu comentário com todo o respeito. Para deduzir que meu projeto tem algum erro não preciso ser tão inteligente, até a avó de 70 anos da minha esposa iria sugerir que o meu projeto tem erros, porém se você fosse sugerir que eu postasse o script do meu arquivo AndroidManifest.xml para verificar qual poderia ser o suporto erro, ai seria mais coerente né? Eu até me disponho para colocar meu projeto no github para analise.

Comment: Um erro no AndroidManifest é apenas uma possibilidade, como está escrito na minha resposta. E não posso pedir esclarecimentos nelas. Se você pudesse fornecer o manifest.xml em algo como um [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), eu agradeceria.